# IRCTC ticket reservation

Tags: trains, tickets, india, indian-railways

I have reserved railway ticket through my IRCTC (Indian railway catering and tourism corporation) online account for my family (Wife, father and mother). But I am not traveling along with them.

In this case do have any issue with this journey? I ask this because a warning note mentioned in my ticket that :-
“This ticket is booked on a personal user ID and cannot be sold by an agent. If bought from an agent by any individual, it is at his/her own risk.”

My address which is given for IRCTC registration is shown in this ticket.

Comment: What's the problem? Your family is travelling using tickets you bought?

Comment: The question is clear.
He has reserved tickets using his personal id fora journey he is not travelling.
Must open the question.

Comment: Of course you can. At least one passenger should carry valid photo id.